# How to extend a common array in yaml

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I want my resulting yaml to be like this:

```
job:
  extends:
    - .common
    - .unique
```

I want to be DRY, so I extract out the common part:

```
.extend_common: &extend_common
  extends:
    - .common
```

Now I want to put it together:

```
job:
  <<: *extend_common
    - .unique
```

But this is not valid yaml.  I have done some search but haven't found a solution.  Is this possible in yaml?  What would be the correct syntax that doesn't require more code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The [YAML merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is not special syntax, only a key in a mapping with special semantics. Hence, it doesn't work in sequences.

YAML isn't a programming language and generally doesn't have such capabilities. Even the merge key is an optional extension not supported by all implementation (and specified for outdated YAML 1.1).

You can use a templating engine like Jinja2 to preprocess your YAML. This is a common solution used by tools like Ansible and SaltStack.